# Can't get PHP form to save datetime to NULL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, null

I'm having a helluva time figuring this one out - it seems to be a well documented question, but none of the solutions go quite far enough to completely solve my problem.

Basically I've got a database for our website that saves upcoming events; occasionally these events have more than one showing, so we have fields where we can put in these dates if it does.  Most of the time, there's just one date to put in, so our extra date fields (date2, date 3, etc) are blank.  If they're **blank**, I want them to be saved to the mysql database as **NULL**.

An example of what I've got for tossing the values to mySQL looks like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['date2']))
        {$date2 = NULL;
        }
    else
        {$date2 = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['date2'])));
        }
```

Which is doing what it's supposed to.  The problem comes when we try to update the variable as follows:

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE events
             SET date2='".mysql_real_escape_string($date2))."',
```

mySQL doesn't know what this value is (obviously, because you can't escape string or format a date on NULL) so it saves the value as 0000-00-00 instead (or 1969-12-31...depending on my attempt to fix the problem).  What I can't figure out is how to input a value for date2 without using ''s.

I tried changing it to **date2 = $date2,** But the code won't execute and tosses up an error.  **date2='$date2',** executes - but again it's not saving NULL correctly (I think because it's saving 'NULL' and not NULL?).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the variable in single quotes:

```
date2='".mysql_real_escape_string($date2))."',
```

Which means you are trying to save a string to the field.

If you want it to be `null` you need to drop the quotes around it.

```
insert into YourTable ('null'); // Will try to insert a string
insert into YourTable (null); // Will try to insert a null
```

Edit: Why not pop it directly into the `if` statement right off the bat?

```
if (empty($_POST['date2']))
{
    $date2 = NULL;
    mysql_query("UPDATE events SET date2=null, ...";
    // This will also work...
    mysql_query("UPDATE events SET date2=".$date2.", ...";
}
else
{
    $date2 = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['date2'])));
    mysql_query("UPDATE events SET date2='".mysql_real_escape_string($date2))."', ...";
}
```

Updated code:

```
$query="update events set ";

if (empty($_POST['date2']))
{
    $date2 = NULL;
    $query.="date2=null, ";
}
else
{
    $date2 = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['date2'])));
    $query.= " date2='".mysql_real_escape_string($date2)."', ";
}

// a few other if statements to finish up the rest of your fields...

$query.=" where someCondition=SomeOtherCondition";
mysql_query($query);
```

On that note, if you are writing this code nice and fresh, you might want to consider starting with [PDO.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and using prepared statements.

Comment: Problem is definitely the quotes in this section, but I can't get the code to WORK when removing them.  As noted above I tried simply **date2 = $date2,** without quotes or anything (adding them into the IF statement when there IS a date) - but it spits out an error that my syntax is wrong.

Comment: @CodyS I have updated my answer - why not just deal with it inside the if statement?

Comment: This is where my noobish-ness comes into play;  It's proper form to have multiple mysql_query-ies on a page?  So it'd be fine if had a mysql_query(Update...) for date2, another for date3, and another for the rest of the fields on on the form?

Comment: @CodyS No, running multiple queries (ie, one for each column) would typically be a very bad thing, however, constructing a single query within a bunch of if statements and running it once is certainly workable, I will add an example into my answer.

Comment: @CodyS I have updated my answer again with some code that I think will help you with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you much! The code had been working until recently when we switched servers - I think an upgrade somewhere behind the scenes highlighted some of the errors in my less-than-legit code.  Perhaps rebuilding the page along the lines of your examples would be better in the long run.

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: There's an extra ")" in the escape string that gets passed if there's a date in the field - but otherwise this works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize your database. Add table `dates` with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`dates` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `event_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
INDEX (  `event_id` ));
```

For each event the table keep one or more dates. If date2, date3 are blank, table has no record for them.